# Fonts getting smaller when _theme.less is created

Tags: magento2, theme, css, fonts

I'm running 2.1.2 but since 2.0.1 I'm facing the same problem.

I have a custom theme and when I created file "_theme.less" under my template's structure (web/css/source) all those icons based on fonts get smaller. I mean Cart, Heart (wish list) and Bars (to compare). The weird thing is that the problem persist even if this _theme.less file is totally empty. When I remove the file everything went back to normal (without my customs, of course)

My custom template has Luma as parent so I tried copying all Luma's fonts to my own folder, also copied Blanks fonts but didnt work:

myuser@server: app/design/frontend/CustomTemplates/MyTemplate/web/fonts# ls
Blank-Theme-Icons.eot  Blank-Theme-Icons.ttf   Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2  Luma-Icons.svg  Luma-Icons.woff   selection.json
Blank-Theme-Icons.svg  Blank-Theme-Icons.woff  Luma-Icons.eot           Luma-Icons.ttf  Luma-Icons.woff2

I'm flushing the cache before testing.

Any idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should put your code in the file `source/_extend.less`. Putting it in `_theme.less` tells magento to overwrite the base theme file which is not what you want.

Comment: I made the same mistake, (using theme instead of extend) this fixed my issues this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

When you're extending a theme and overriding _theme.less you need to copy the variables from the original _theme.less.

This is something you can find in the css guide from Magento:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html